# Tethering iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5s, and a wireless plan that permits tethering. I am wondering if there are any consequences of frequent tethering. For example, if my phone was plugged in to a charger and tethered for a couple of hours every day, would this lead to faster than normal "wear and tear" for the phone, since the activity is so heavy? Or is this a completely ordinary task?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can simply do this. Just be sure you have enough power to keep it running, as the battery will drain fast on tethering. But since you mention it being plugged in a charger - go for it.

Comment: Great, thank you. In general, would it cause the battery to be significantly weaker over time, compared to normal use?

Comment: @5sstar No, you just have to charge it more often as it drains more battery. There's no significant proof this will *kill* your battery. Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you're satisfied by my answer. Thanks.